# How To Query IDs that have different Patient Names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct

First, I understand that I should have a Primary Key on a Value Patient ID.  A project was performed for ID conversions that did not go very well.  So now I need to find all Patient IDs that have differnt Patient Names.  There are 4 different DBs>Tables that contain info.  For now I selected them into a Temp DB.  Because I actually need all PIDs to be distinct across those DBs.  Our application has tools to keep that synchronized.  But due to some bad SQL work, I need to synchronize all the Data again.

```
PID     NAME     
1234    Johnson
1234    Johnson
4567    Jones
4567    Alexander
```

I am trying to write a query that will return the results of PID 4567 + NAME Values of Jones and Alexander.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: What exactly is the result you are expecting? Two rows? One row?

Comment: What's the expected result if you also add (4567, Sherman)?

Comment: Eray got me the results I was wanting.  I wanted all results that 1) had a same Patient ID but 2) Different MRNs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Min(PID), Name FROM [Table] 
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING Count(PID) = 1
```

Comment: Uh, what if there was only one 1234 Johnson

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a self-join. Please try this:

```
create table #temp
(id int, name varchar(30))

insert into #temp values (1,'johnson')
insert into #temp values (1,'johnson')
insert into #temp values (2,'james')
insert into #temp values (2,'Alex')

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE id IN (
   SELECT a.id FROM #temp a
   JOIN #temp b on b.id = a.id AND b.name <> a.name 
)
```

Comment: If you are going to do a join there is better way to do it

Comment: Will this work if there are more than 2 names for a given id?

Comment: Yes this worked perfect!  Got me exactly what I needed.

Comment: I am happy I helped. I'd appreciate if you select the answer as the "correct answer" by clicking the tick on the left. Thanks @Kevin3142

Comment: I am new... and it doesn't let me do that yet.  I did try!

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do it

```
select p.pid, max(name), min(name), count(*) as cnt 
from p 
group by pid 
having max(name) <> min(name)
```

or

```
select p1.pid, p1.name, p2.name  
from p p1
join p p2 
  on p1.pid = p2.pid 
 and p1.name < p2.name  
order by p1.pid, p1.name, p2.name
```

Comment: both of these solutions are really only targeted at pairs of duplicates not multiple occurrences e.g. 3.  The first would break down completely and the second would show 3 combinations of names.

Comment: @Matt It works.  If you have something better then it is your option to post an answer.  To characterize as break down completely is a bit dramatic.  Good day.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT PID,NAME      
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PID,NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) =1
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP is asking for

Comment: @paparazzo, I think it will return 4567 with both names?

Comment: Uh, what if there was only one 1234   Johnson

Comment: @paparazzo, right... not sure what is the purpose of that task ;)

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of ways and some more optimized than others depending on which RDBMS system you are using.  But typically this is a 2 step operations.

1) Find all of the PIDs that have more than 1 Name associated with it
2) Relate back to get the rest of the data you are seeking.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
    PID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO #T (PID,Name) VALUES (1234,'Johnson'),(1234,'Johnson'),(4567,'Jones'),(4567,'Alexander')


SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          PID
       FROM
          #T t1
       GROUP BY
          PID
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Name) > 1
    ) dupes
    INNER JOIN #T t2
    ON dupes.PID = t2.PID
```

It is important when using a method such as the join or IN above that you use DISTINCT name because simplying counting * or name will return multiple occurrences of the same PID to name combination not simply duplicates.

If you only want the duplicate not all of the combinations.  Using a RowNumber() or something can help you get to the answer a little more efficiently too.  Or you can also use a method such as looking for existence of a non identical record, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.PID, t1.Name
FROM
    #T t1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #t t2 WHERE t1.PID = t2.PID AND t1.Name <> t2.Name)
```

This way could perform faster for you depending on data sets etc.  I would tend to stay away from solutions that use IN for cases like these.